# How do I stop magit popups on commit?

Tags: magit, popup

When I do a commit, magit popups the diff in a separate wm window. I'd like it to show the diff in the same wm window and just split into a different wm window.

I've tried [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19915/10949), but it hasn't worked.

magit 20200805.1104
emacs 26.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `magit-display-buffer-function` option.

Comment: Thanks, `(setq magit-display-buffer-function (quote magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1))` seems to have done it.

Comment: This has worked for commit diffs, but it doesn't seem to work for magit-revision frames which still pop-out (e.g. when pressing Enter on an entry in magit-log). Is there a separate variable for that? Or a way to set this behaviour globally?